# SQL Server how to store multilingual data?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, multilingual, nvarchar

I created a database with collation: `default` & a table with a column has `nvarchar(50)` as its data type. But when I select the data I got "???".
Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What's in the record?

Comment: Try CAST(COl1 AS NVARCHAR(the length you have used in your table structure))

Comment: SQL Server 2010? Also, @sqluser, [that's a dangerous way to cast](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx); please don't recommend it to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must always declare N before inserting any values.

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (Col1) VALUES (N'your text')
```